# Rails doesn't send object as a param error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a controller that handles articles, and recently implemented the edit and create action that way:

```
def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])

      if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end 
end
```

The error occours when I try to edit an article showing the message: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wsdl.jpg)

I'm using a form partial to load the layout this way:

```
<%= render "form", article: @article %>
```

After trying to save an new article the edit action works properly and the body error message doesn't shows if trying to save without the requirements. What should I do so solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe try to add `if article.errors.any?` before you loop through each error. Rails may complain it cannot find the errors it has to loop through.

Comment: @Maxence that won't do anything really since the error mesage is `undefined method 'errors' for nil:Nilclass` which tells us that the local assign `article` is being passed (otherwise it would `undefined method 'arcticle'` but its nil. This code here doens't explain the issue but my guess is that `@article` is inadvertantly getting re-assigned or isn't actually getting assigned in the first place (unsaved code, wrong code running etc). And the way to diagose any kind of nil error is by setting breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for discuss sake, it was caused by some stucked configuration (apparently) at my computer, the solution was to clone the entire project to another folder, what solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way altogether to handle rendering errors - just access the object wrapped by the form builder:

```erb
<%= form_with(model: article) do |form| %>
  <% if form.object.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% form.object.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>    
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This lets you DRY out the rendering of errors messages without having to know the name of variable which corresponds to the model instance wrapped by the form.

However you also have a classic nil error - `@article` is most likely nil. And this isn't an issue we can actually help you with since it cannot be reproduced if we take the code in the question at face value. Like often with stackoverflow the actual problem it lurking somewhere outside of picture.

The debug this code you need to ensure that the code you think is running is actually running and set a series of breakpoints to verify that it is indeed being set and is being passed correctly all the way to the view.

Comment: Just got the same error message

Comment: The edit link at show page is set this way (https://prnt.sc/AXA6tefUc8qq) don't think there's a problem with it but sending or not @article as a parameter to the link doesn't seems to change nothing and even more strange is after creating a new article, the edit action works perfectly with the new and old ones

Comment: As I tried to explain this won't actually magically fix your issue. You need to track down and fix the nil error - this isn't something we can do for you and learning to do this is a basic skill that every programmer needs to know how to do. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: I would learn these other topics after I finished the getting started one to have a consistent knowledge about the framework, but now gonna start the debbuging one, anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

I see that you change `article` to `@article` in `edit.html.erb`. Because `article` does not exist. `article` exists when you `render "form", article: @article` use in `_form.html.erb`

```
  <% @article.erors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| 
    <div><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
```

But i think you don't show errors in `edit.html.erb`

In `edit.html.erb` file

```
  <%= render "form", article: @article %>
```

In _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: article) do |form| %>
  <% if article.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% article.errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>    
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :title, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

P/S: That's my opinion, if anyone has any ideas, please leave a comment. I thank you very much

Comment: He's passing the instance variable as a local assign to the partial `render "form", article: @article`.

Comment: But he puts `article.errors` in `edit.html.erb`.

Comment: No. That would most likely result in `undefined method 'arcticle'`. The code in the screenshot may actually be the partial and not `edit.html.erb`. It just shows the trace from where it started rendering.